# launching tomcat7 at local host has an error

Tags: eclipse, tomcat7

I've been trying to install Apache Tomcat 7 with Eclipse Helios to try web applications.
But I am unable to run `webcontents`. It gives the following message in Eclipse:

```
Several ports ( 8090, 8009) required by Tomcat v7.0 Server at localhost are already in use. The server may already be running in another process, or a system process may be using the port. To start this server you will need to stop the other process or change the port number(s).
```

I've tried changing the port numbers and reinstalling Tomcat but the problem remains unresolved.
I can see the Apache Tomcat/7.0.27 in browser.

Comment: (if you use windows) try killing the running tomcat by then start it in eclipse kill it with:  TASKKILL /F /IM java.exe /T

Comment: @Daniel please tell me the command. it has error: TASKKILL /F /IM java.exe /T in cmd.

Comment: @Mohsen i wasn't aware thet you got other server beside tomcat... my command was supposed to kill running tomcat (in my windows tomcat process named java.exe)

Answer (score 2):

The error message indicates that Tomcat is *already* running outside of Eclipse. Apparently you've already started it from outside Eclipse and/or you've downloaded and installed it as "Windows Service".

You should stop any running Tomcat instances before using the one integrated in Eclipse. You do not need the "Windows Service" (which is available as EXE file) when you intend to develop with Eclipse/Tomcat. You should be using the core engine (which is available as ZIP file) instead. Stop/uninstall the Windows Service. Download and extract the ZIP file and then integrate it in Eclipse. You need to change ports by doubleclicking the Tomcat entry in Eclipse, not by editing the `server.xml` externally.

Answer (score 0):

netstat -aon | findstr "8080"

use this command to find pid and then using task manager sto this process and then try running it may help

Comment: @PeterPerháč in 8080 i have IIS. i want to use another port. i have changed the port number to 8090. i try a lot of port. but i still have the problem.

Answer (score 0):

One way to go about resolving this issue would be to leave the ports used by other processess alone and configure your tomcat instance to use different port numbers. i am sure it's as simple as editing a config file somewhere. All web servers can easily be reconfigured to use different port numbers. Give it a try.